# Postgres: Generate 1-per-parent id sequences for child ids with no holes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I want a – can I call it a sub-sequence ? – to generate identity for child lines. A sequence per parent entity, starting at 1 with no holes. That is, each parent's childrens Ids should start at 1 and increment. What is a simple and reliable solution?

#### Detail, if it helps

- My application inserts rows into a child table for order LineItems.
- The application requires LineItems be numbered consecutively from 1
- The LineItems table itself also has child tables, in this case Variation.
- After insert, I return the inserted row with the new sequential LineItemId
- The app doesn't allow deletions

Current code (the @ symbols marks *input parameters*):

```
Insert Into Lineitems (Jobid,Id,Stage, Costprice, Sellprice, Customdescription)
        Values (@JobId,
        -- *Calculate next line id for this jobid*
        @Stage,@Costprice,@Sellprice,@Customdescription)
;
Insert Into Variations (Lineitemjobid,Lineitemid,InstructedBy,InstructionDate,Type)
    Values (@jobId,
           *Use the just-inserted line id for this jobid*
           @Instructedby, @Instructiondate, @Variation_Type)
;
Select * from ...etc... 
Where (JobId,Id)=(@jobId, *Use the just-inserted line id for this jobid*)
```

The places marked `*Calculate...*` & `*Use...*` are where I want my 1-based, no-holes, per-parent, subsequence.

#### My First Effort

I create a view to get currentval/next val

```
Create View Lineitemidseq(Jobid, Currentval, Nextval) As
        Select Jobs.Id                    As Jobid,
               Coalesce(Max(L.Id), 0)     As Currentval,
               1 + Coalesce(Max(L.Id), 0) As Nextval
        From Jobs Left Join Lineitems L On Jobs.Id = L.Jobid
        Group By Jobs.Id
```

And then I can fill in my calculations for `next lineid` & `last-inserted-in-this-session-lineid`:

`Next` : `(Select Nextval from Lineitemidseq Where JobId=@jobId)`

`Last-inserted-in-this-session` : `(Select Currentval from Lineitemidseq Where JobId=@jobId)`

You can see the flaw, albeit at low probability. Because I have a child of the child, if 2 people add lines simultaneously, I could pick up a wrong CurrentVal in statements 2 & 3.

#### So:

- Presumably I could fix this with an explicit lock for the 3-line transaction. Is there a better way?
- If not, what is a reasonably minimalist lock that would provide correctness for such a small transaction?

Comment: Is ther any reason you don;t just use `ROW_NUMBER` when you select? What do you want to happen if a row gets deleted?

Comment: Yes, good question: Rows may not be deleted, they can be moved to status cancelled, I'll add that. Row_number() would replace `Max(L.Id)` in my View?

Comment: Yes it would, although you would have to take into account the `left join` returning no rows. And just remove the `Lineitems.id` column completely, just calculate it on the fly

Comment: A `sequence` can never guarantee that there are no holes (e.g. because of rollbacks)

Comment: indeed! So I need something else. A REPEATABLE READ transaction is the best I've got soo far?

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest thing I can see is to put the 3 lines inside:

```
Begin Transaction Isolation Level REPEATABLE READ
;
Insert ...
Insert ...
Select ...
;
Commit
```

Repeatable Read is the level that guarantees that

`(Select ... From Lineitemidseq Where JobId=@jobId)`

in statements 2 and 3 is consistent with

`(Select ... From Lineitemidseq Where JobId=@jobId)`

in statement 1.

Where “consistent” means, unaffected by any concurrent transaction.

This amount of locking seems like the bare minimum (or close to) that can do the job?